# Independence of $X$ and $X^2$

Tags: probability-distributions, independence

If I have a random variable $X$ where the pdf is always positive, are $X$ and $X^2$ independent? Never, sometimes, or always?
I was thinking to either find the pdf of $X^2$ or the cdf. Then find the joint pdf/cdf. But without the actual value of the pdf for $X$ I'm not sure how to do that. Is there another way?
Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: pdf is positive for any real value of X

Edit 2: X is a continuous random variable

Comment: the pdf is always positive. i.e. for any $x\in\mathbb R$, or $X$ takes only positive values?

Comment: Any value of x yes

Comment: Do you have in mind orthogonality, as opposed to independence?

Comment: No I definitely mean independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is a non-negative RV and not constant, then $X$ and $X^2$ are positively correlated, and hence not independent.  Here's why: The covariance between $X$ and $X^2$ is by definition the expectation of
$$
(X-EX)\left(X^2 - E(X^2)\right).\tag1
$$
Rewrite (1) as
$$
(X-EX)\left(X^2-(EX)^2\right) + (X-EX)\left((EX)^2-E(X^2)\right).\tag2
$$
The second term of (2) has expectation zero. Meanwhile, the first term of (2) can be rewritten
$$
(X-EX)^2(X + EX),\tag3
$$
which shows that (3) is a nonnegative and non-constant RV. Therefore (3) has positive expectation, so so does (1), which means the required covariance is positive.

(Assuming all required expectations exist.) Geometrically, the random pair ($X$, $X^2$) lives on the right half of the curve $y=x^2$, so the correlation is positive if $X$ is not constant.

Comment: Is the fact that f(x) is positive used implicitly here? Also why does being constant allow them to be independent? My 3 choices are: not independent, independent, may or may not be independent.

Comment: This argument proves a more general result, which doesn't require a density for $X$. If it is known that $X$ has a density $f(x)$  then it is impossible for $X$ to be constant, so by the above argument, $X$ and $X^2$ are for sure not independent.

Comment: As for constant random variables being independent, this is a 'degenerate' result that follows from the definition of independence. If $X$ is a constant RV then $P(X\in A)$ is either zero or one depending on whether $A$ contains the constant or not. In either case we have $P(X\in A, Y\in B) = P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$ for any other random variable $Y$ and any choice of $A$ and $B$, which means $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Why does having a density make X non-constant by default? What if f(x)=3? Isn't that a constant pdf?

Comment: A constant random variable is concentrated at one point, so it cannot have a pdf. Put another way, if a RV has a pdf then it cannot be concentrated at one point, so it cannot be constant. As for $f(x)=3$, you are confusing the pdf with the random variable. The pdf being constant is not the same as the random variable being constant.

Answer (score 2):

Given that $X^2\in A^2$ for some set $A$ in the Borel σ-algebra of $\mathbb R$, then you know that $X\in \pm A$. Take $A$ such that $0<P(X\in \pm A)<1$ (this $A$ exists due to your assumption that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$), then $$P(X\in \pm A\mid X^2\in A^2)=1\neq P(X\in \pm A)$$ hence $X$ and $X^2$ are always dependent under this assumption. Otherwise, (see the comment in the other answer) you can create a degenerate random variable for which $X$ and $X^2$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Surely $X $ and $X^2$ are **not** independent! As soon as you know the value of one, the value of the other becomes determined!

Comment: If $P(X=88)=1$ then $X$ and $X^2$ are apparently independent, though you might argue this does not have a density

Comment: X is continuous if that matters.